# You have an error in your SQL syntax: syntax to use near 'ID="" at line 1

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I keep getting this error

> 'ID="" at line 1

here's my code :

```
        public void DeleteRecord(){
        String sql="delete from  issueditems where Item ID=?";
    try{

      pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      pst.setString(1, jt4.getText());
      pst.execute();
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Looks like the code and the error messages doesn't fit. Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Do you have a trigger?

Comment: Probably jt4.getText returns null or empty string

Comment: right i did set my jt4 setText("") after clicking the action button(removed it) and now I'm getting new error : Syntax error : near 'ID='10006272" at line 1

Comment: There seems to be a space character between "Item" and "ID" - probably your SQL statement should read `"delete from  issueditems where ItemID=?"`

Comment: Note that this is a different question from the one originally asked

Answer (score 1):

check `jt4.getText()` is **null** or **empty**.

check `ID` field datatype is **int** or **varchar**.

if `ID` is  int type. try modify `pst.setString(1, jt4.getText())` is `pst.setInt(1,Integer.parseInt(jt4.getText()))`

Comment: Changed it to varchar now i forgot about it and now i'm getting new error : Syntax error : near 'ID='10006272" at line 1

Comment: You shouldn't change your database columns type, you should fix your code, put some validations and conversions to make sure your code always pass to the query a valid, not null number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what database you are using, but I also don't know any database where "Item ID" is a valid column name. The column is probably either named "ItemID" or "Item_ID" and you need to change your SQL statement accordingly - either

```
delete from  issueditems where ItemID=?
```

or

```
delete from  issueditems where Item_ID=?
```

---

With your current statement (`delete from  issueditems where Item ID=?`) the database sees a column name "Item" and expects an operator ('=', '<', '>', 'LIKE' or something similar), but finds another identifier "ID" and doesn't know what to do with this identifier.